# cannot load such file -- socket (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, ubuntu, rubygems

OS: Ubuntu Server 11.10

I'm getting this error trying to "gem install rails".

```
/home/bindiry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- socket (LoadError)

from /home/bindiry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/bindiry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is my installation process:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unzip curl aptitude
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
echo '[[ -s "/home/bindiry/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/home/bindiry/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*' >> ~/.bashrc

source .bashrc

sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev \
curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev \
libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison g++ nodejs \
libapr1 libaprutil1 libneon27-gnutls libsvn1 subversion pkg-config

rvm get stable
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm 1.9.3 --default
ruby -v
# ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]
```

any ideas would be helpful.

thanks.

**update:**

I solve the problem.

Make sure you have uninstall 1.9.3.

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

done.

Answer (score 0):

Install socket

```
sudo apt-get install socket
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.

Make sure you have uninstall 1.9.3.

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```